# Unable to nail memory leak detected by valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind

Below is the pattern of new/delete operators in my program. Valgrind says that memory is "definitely lost". I couldn't quite get where the leak is. Is there something wrong with my usage of new/delete operators.

```
 class Generic
 {
        GenericInterface *gInterface; //GenericInterface is abstract class

        public:
           Generic ()
           {
                gInterface = NULL;
           }
           ~Generic ()
           {
               delete gInterface;
           }
           void Create()
           {
           gInterface = new Specific();
           }
    };

    class Specific : public GenericInterface
    {
       MyClass* _myClass; 

    public:
      Specific()
      {
         _myClass = new MyClass;
      }

      ~Specific()
      {
         delete _myClass; 
      }

    };

    int main()
    {
       Generic g;
       g.Create();
    }
```

valgrind says that memory is lost.

```
==2639== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 45
==2639==    at 0x4026351: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:255)
==2639==    by 0x804D77C: Specific::Specific() (Specific.cc:13)
==2639==    by 0x804DAFC: Generic::Create() (Generic.cc:58)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not following the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  If your class manages resources that need to be cleaned up, you *must* declare a destructor, copy constructor, and copy assignment operator.  Neither of your classes has a copy constructor or a copy assignment operator.

Really, you should almost certainly just be using a smart pointer like `unique_ptr` from C++0x; `shared_ptr` from Boost, C++ TR1, and C++0x; or `scoped_ptr` from Boost.

The likely issue causing this specific problem is that you have forgotten to make the base-class `GenericInterface` destructor `virtual`, so the wrong destructor is being called and the `MyClass` object that you dynamically create in `Specific` is never destroyed.

`delete`ing an object via a pointer to one of its base classes results in undefined behavior if the base class destructor is not declared `virtual` (that means bad things will happen, ranging from memory leaks to crashes).

Comment: When I put `virtual ~GenericInterface()=0;`,I get Undefined reference to `~GenericInterface()` error in `Specific` destructor.

Comment: @Meebo:  It shouldn't be pure because the derived class destructor has to call it.  You need to define it (`GenericInterface::~GenericInterface() { }`).

Answer (score 2):

Your `GenericInterface` destructor probably is not virtual, so only the `GenericInterface` destructor is getting called when `gInterface` is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Does your GenericInterface class declare a virtual destructor?  If not, the Specific class's destructor won't get called, and thus the "delete _myClass" line won't be executed.

Just another way C++ makes your life more interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Generic class destructor you should also check the gInterface pointer before deleting it. If Create() is not called before the object is destroyed it will cause problems. If your c++ compiler doesn't throw on new failures your other class may also do the same thing